# How to perform selenium actions on my application from a particular page

Tags: selenium, appium, cucumber-jvm, appium-android

appium version: 1.10
I am using windows 10

I am performing  selenium actions on the application page, where I can not be able to perform actions from a particular page 
Page starting from native view then comes web view (not working for both),where i can perform these actions for other modules in my application

But this works for a device:
device name : vivo Y21L
android version : 5.1

I tried with other android versions like 4.4,6.0,7.0,8.0 where this not works

If i perform action manually(click on a element manually and redirect back to same page)while running automation script it works properly

I have tried by using:

1.ID, Xpath 
2.printing page source (where i can find the id,xpath)
3.switch from native to web view

Comment: Please check once by downgrading your appium to 1.9 version.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, I still get the same issue with the update you mentioned

Comment: Can you please update the question with the error logs? And can you also confirm that your app is native android having web view and not created using any other technology like ionic or something else?